# Preventing Horizontal Expansion of div when screen/content changes

Tags: css, html

I am having an issue with my main content. As the screen is resized or the text of the main content gets larger, it expands downwards as expected, but it also goes UNDER my menu on the left hand side, which I do not want.

Can someone vet my code and tell me how to fix this?

Image:
[image: Image of what I want vs what is occurring]

```
<html>

<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>page title</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="pagediv">
<div class="headermain">
Title
</div>
<div class="headerquote">
 quote
</div>
<div class="menu">
<p><a href="link">Home</a></p>
<p><a href="link">About the Artist</a></p>
<p><a href="link>"Blog</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Artist Statement</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Inspiration</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Art Gallery</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Exhibits</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Store</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Commissioning</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Contact</a></p>
</div>

<div class="artist_pic">
<img src="picture link">    
</div>

<div class="content_type_a">
<p>CONTENT HERE</p>
</div>   

<div class="footer">
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
body {
background-color: black;

}

/*contains the page in the center of the browser*/
.pagediv {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 70%;
background-color: black;
}

/*Main title bar at the top of the page*/
.headermain {
background-color: black;
font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 200%;
font-style: bold;
display: block;
    width: 100%;
padding-top: 30px;
}

/*Quote after the main title*/
.headerquote {
background-color: black;
font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
font-size: 110%;
font-style: italic;
color: #FFF;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-left: 60px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
display: block;
}

 /*headerquote bottom border*/
.headerquote {
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
} 


.menu {
background-color: black;
width: auto;
font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 110%;
font-style: bold;
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
clear: right;
clear: both;
padding-right: 15px;
height: px;
}

.menu a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 110%;
}

.menu a:hover {
color: #FFF;
font-size: 110%;
text-decoration:underline;
}

.menu a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 110%;

}

.artist_pic {
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
clear: none;
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.content_type_a {
background-color: black;
font-family: Arial, serif;
font-size: 100%;
color: #FFF;
width: auto;
float: 40%;
clear: none;
display: block;
text-align:justify;

}
.construction {
background-color: black;
font-family: Arial, serif;
font-size: 100%;
color: #FFF;
display: block;
text-align:justify;
}

.construction img {
background-color: transparent;
height: 150px;
border: none;
width: auto;
font-family: Arial
color: #FFF;
font-size: 100%;
font-style: bold;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 0px 0px 100px;
}

.footer {

}
```

Comment: Wow. You guys are super helpful, and really fast with responses. I really appreciate this community. I'll be back often now, I'm sure. Haha...

Comment: Try to concentrate on the question. No need for thanking in advance, unnecessary explanations, tags in the title and stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You could remove

```
text-align:justify;
```

from the `.content_type_a` style and add

```
position: absolute;
left: 220px;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/bULaF/

Answer (score 0):

There are ready-made solutions for this problem. They are called grid systems.

They have been invented to mitigate this problem among many others.

See these, for example:

- [960 grid system](http://960.gs)
- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) - This is a CSS/JS
  framework, but it has a fairly decent grid system. It might be
  overkill for what you're trying to do, but maybe it will help you
  style your forms too (if you'll have any)

They have a (very) small learning curve, but I think it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu {
float: left;
}
```

Is the reason, if the menu is not taller than the content that is allowed to float around it then when the content goes below the menu it has more space.

A wrapper and margin-left:negative value is one of the solutions, normally with a fixed width for the menu.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="menu">
<p><a href="link">Home</a></p>
<p><a href="link">About the Artist</a></p>
<p><a href="link>"Blog</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Artist Statement</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Inspiration</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Art Gallery</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Exhibits</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Store</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Commissioning</a></p>
<p><a href="link">Contact</a></p>
</div>

<div class="artist_pic">
<img src="picture link">    
</div>

<div class="content_type_a">
<p>CONTENT HERE</p>
</div> 
<div style="clear:both"><!-- note we should clear floats with some type of content or tag --></div>
</div> <!-- end wrapper -->
```

Now add left margins

```
.wrapper {
left-margin:200px;
}
.menu {
left-margin:-200px;
width:200px;
}
```

Now content will not wrap around menu, regardless if it is floating or not.

Comment: I did not place all your CSS in my answer so that the answer is clearly seen. percentages for widths and margins can be used by become confusing typically one does not want the menu to narrow, IE typically it is a fixed width. Clearing floats is not a must (footer width = 100%) but since the wrapper would be where the background goes if the floats are not cleared then the background does not go to the bottom of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Your floatting image should be inside the container aside the menu.

To not allow aside/main container to go under the floatting menu, just trigger the layout with `overflow`. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pmZe7/)**

Your CSS for your main container becomes:

```
.content_type_a {
background-color: black;
font-family: Arial, serif;
font-size: 100%;
color: #FFF;
width: auto;
overflow:hidden;/* here mind outside and inside floatting elements*/
clear: none;
display: block;
text-align:justify;
}
```

---

`Float:40%;` **does not exist** , it only takes : `none`, `right` or `left` as proper values.

Comment: I used this solution, along with a few others. It works perfectly. New code:

    <div class="content_type_a">
    <div class="artist_pic">
    <img src="picture link">    
    </div>
    <p>buncha stuff</p>
</div>  

css:

    .content_type_a {
 background-color: black;
 font-family: Arial, serif;
 font-size: 100%;
 color: #FFF;
 width: auto;
 float: 40%;
 clear: none;
 position: relative;
 display: table;
 text-align: justify;